# MySQL: combination of LEFT JOIN and ORDER BY is slow

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, query-performance

There are two tables: `posts` (~5,000,000 rows) and `relations` (~8,000 rows).

`posts` columns:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  source_id  |  content  |  date (int)  |
-------------------------------------------------
```

`relations` columns:

```
---------------------------
|  source_id  |  user_id  |
---------------------------
```

I wrote a MySQL query for **getting 10 most recent rows from `posts` which are related to a specific user**:

```
SELECT      p.id, p.content
FROM        posts AS p
LEFT JOIN   relations AS r
ON          r.source_id = p.source_id
WHERE       r.user_id = 1
ORDER BY    p.date DESC
LIMIT       10
```

However, it takes ~30 seconds to execute it.

I already have indexes at `relations` for `(source_id, user_id)`, `(user_id)` and for `(source_id)`, `(date)`, `(date, source_id)` at `posts`.

`EXPLAIN` results:

[image: EXPLAIN results]

How can I optimize the query?

Comment: Note that this renders as an inner join!

Comment: Try replacing WHERE with AND.

Comment: And please post the result of ’EXPLAIN SELECT ...’

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, you might need an additional index on r.user_id alone and select FROM relations and LEFT JOIN posts

Comment: @JanPapenbrock replacing WHERE with AND returns the results that are not related to a user. Added the EXPLAIN results to the post.

Comment: @JanPapenbrock yes, forgot to mention, I already have r.user_id alone as an index as well.

Comment: Do you *want* this to be an outer join? Then you can simply **remove** it completely from your query and only keep `select id, content from posts order by "date" desc limit 10`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I just want a query that selects _"10 most recent rows from `posts` which are related to a user"_ much faster than my query :)

Comment: @Osvaldas: Your query wouldn't apply "which are related to a user", but "which are related to a user or not" instead, if you hadn't make a mistake in your outer join (putting criteria in `WHERE` instead of `ON`). You want an *inner* join - or no join at all rather. See my answer on this.

Answer (score 2):

Your WHERE clause renders your outer join a mere inner join (because in an outer-joined pseudo record user_id will always be null, never 1).

If you really want this to be an outer join then it is completely superfluous, because *every* record in `posts` either has or has not a match in `relations` of course. Your query would then be

```
select id, content 
from posts 
order by "date" desc limit 10;
```

If you don't want this to be an outer join really, but *want* a match in `relations`, then we are talking about existence in a table, an `EXISTS` or `IN` clause hence:

```
select id, content
from posts
where source_id in
(
  select source_id
  from relations
  where user_id = 1
)
order by "date" desc
limit 10;
```

There should be an index on `relations(user_id, source_id)` - in this order, so we can select `user_id` 1 first and get an array of all desired `source_id` which we then look up.

Of course you also need an index on `posts(source_id)` which you probably have already, as `source_id` is an ID. You can even speed things up with a composite index `posts(source_id, date, id, content)`, so the table itself doesn't have to be read anymore - all the information needed is in the index already.

**UPDATE:** Here is the related `EXISTS` query:

```
select id, content
from posts p
where exists
(
  select *
  from relations r
  where r.user_id = 1
  and r.source_id = p.source_id
)
order by "date" desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however I had this answer before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36661096/1696898 - no affection in performance.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this. So you do have the indexes mentioned and still the query is slow? I would consider this a great flaw in MySQL. Are you using an old version maybe? I'll add the related `EXISTS` query, maybe MySQL has an issue with `IN`.

Comment: Yes, I tried the indexes you suggested. Same with the `EXISTS`. MySQL version – the latest one, SSD server. I experimented by removing `order by` – works fast. Works also fast if I remove the `user_id=1`. There's just something fundamentally wrong with my query, which probably scans all of those 5 million rows.

Comment: No. Your query (apart from the unnecessary outer join) is good, as are my queries. It must be the DBMS making mistakes. It is either using indexes when it should not or vice versa. If for instance 90% of the posts had a user 1 entry then the posts table should not be read via an index. How many source IDs have user 1? How many posts exist in table `posts` for these IDs? The index `relations(user_id, source_id)` is a unique index, correct?

Comment: For `user_id=1` there is 1,031 `source_id`'s and 454,006 rows in `posts`. It's simple index.

Comment: That's many. The best way would probably to read all `posts` records sequentially and check user 1 existence for each post on-the-fly. But even if the DBMS does so, there are still half a million records to sort. Your best might be a composite index covering all needed columns, as the afore mentioned `posts(source_id, date, id, content)`. But you tried that one already. *Maybe* the index in another order `posts(date, source_id, id, content)` might help, as the DBMS would get all records sorted from the index and could look up the users sequentially. Cluthcing at a straw actually :-|

Answer (score 1):

You could put an index on the date column of the posts table, I believe that will help the order-by speed.

You could also try reducing the number of results before ordering with some additional where statements.  For example if you know the that there will likely be ten records with the correct user_id today, you could limit the date to just today (or N days back depending on your actual data).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention – there's already an index for `date` at `posts`. I see your point, however, there's nothing else to limit it to – the date could be any.

Comment: This article talks a bit about the issues: https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/01/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-optimization/.  The author mentions that a multiple column index on the filtering (user_id) and ordering (date) columns together could create better results than each alone.

Comment: You probably had `source_id` in mind, rather than `user_id` since it's in the other table. I added an index for `(source_id, date)`, however, the performance is still very poor.

Comment: Whoops!  This is what happens when you use Stack Overflow late at night.  I actually thought that they were in the same table.  That gives me an idea: you would be able able to modify your schema to switch user_id with source_id if user_id and source_id are a 1 to 1 relation.  Alternatively you could denormalize these two tables (see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/when-should-you-denormalize).  I think it depends on how badly you want this query to run faster.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    SELECT p.id, p.content FROM posts AS p
    WHERE p.source_id IN (SELECT source_id FROM relations WHERE user_id = 1)
    ORDER BY  p.date DESC
    LIMIT       10
```

Comment: It took even longer – 60s – to execute it.

Comment: subqueries are always slower than join. i thought it is slow because it maybe included duplicated rows. anyways.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider the following :-

Firstly, you only want the 10 most recent rows from posts which are related to a user. So, an `INNER JOIN` should do just fine.

```
SELECT      p.id, p.content
FROM        posts AS p
JOIN        relations AS r
ON          r.source_id = p.source_id
WHERE       r.user_id = 1
ORDER BY    p.date DESC
LIMIT       10
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is needed if you want to fetch the records which do not have a `relations` mapping. Hence, doing the `LEFT JOIN` results in a full table scan of the left table, which as per your info, contains ~5,000,000 rows. This could be the root cause of your query.

For further optimisation, consider moving the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT      p.id, p.content
FROM        posts AS p
JOIN        relations AS r
ON          (r.source_id = p.source_id AND r.user_id = 1)
ORDER BY    p.date DESC
LIMIT       10
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, however, still same ~30s of execution.

Comment: Whoa.. That's quite surprising. I am a little unsure of composite indexes. I once had a bad performance slowdown due to a composite index. So, I'd blindly try removing the composite indexes for `(source_id, user_id)` at `relations` and `(date, source_id)` at `posts`.

Comment: I also tried different variations of indexes, but non of these had any effect.

Comment: Probably the only other thing that comes to my mind is if your queries are getting executed like a 'batch', every 30 seconds ? Can you see if the `explain` plan shows any improvements ?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` for your query is exactly the same. No _batch_ thing, because if I remove ordering – it's fast as lightning. The query is simply wrong at some point.

Comment: What data type is the date column?

Comment: It's `INT` and values are Unix Timestamps.

Comment: `date` is an `INT` column..!!??!! This is the first time I'm hearing of such an implementation. I am not aware how MySQL performance varies for dates in the UNIX Timestamps in an INT column.

Comment: Unix Timestamps are simple INT's like 1426607571, which is perfect for MySQL.

Comment: Even doing `ORDER BY p.id` instead of `date` doesn't interfere the performance anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with a composite index on relations :

```
INDEX source_user (user_id,source_id)
```

and change the query to this :

```
SELECT      p.id, p.content
FROM        posts AS p
INNER JOIN   relations AS r 
ON ( r.user_id = 1 AND r.source_id = p.source_id )
ORDER BY    p.date DESC
LIMIT       10
```

Comment: There was a suggestion like this posted here before – no affection in performance.

Comment: In this query you can remove `relations` altogether; it doesn't influence the result. But as already explained, an outer join is not appropriate for what Osvaldas *actually* wants.

Comment: Indeed an `INNER JOIN` is better here, I still adapted my query even if OP said the composite index doesn't change anything.